# Missing layer in GeoPackages after creation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, geopackage

I have a very strange behaviour with QGIS 3.22.
When I create a new table in the GeoPackage in the browser panel, it often happens that this table is created but is not visible in the QGIS browser. Even if I connect directly to the GeoPackage and display all layers, it does not appear. However, if I make a Select * query, it finds the table, and if I try to create it again, it shows me that it has already been created.

What could be the reason for this? Simply a bug?

Comment: Is there a way to make that happen every time? Is the same GPKG open in some other places? I made some simple tests but I did not face that issue.

Comment: It isn't open in other places, but i do have several QGIS Versions 3.16, 3.22 installed. It happens often but it is not constantly reproducible. the same db works without any problems on another computer, which is why I suspected qgis.